# ArcObjects Style of a symbol chosen with the ISymbolSelector interface

Tags: arcobjects, symbology, vb

I am trying to store the properties of a SimpleMarkerSymbol symbol selected by the user using the ISymbolSelector interface.

I plan to store the size, colour and style number in a file.

I can get the size and colour of the selected symbol but cannot locate the style.

If the user selects one of the Simple Marker Symbols without changing the size or colour then my code works. If they change anything, the code cannot find the style in the style gallery.

Even though I modify the Style gallery enumeration so that they have the same size and colour as the chosen symbol the clone test fails.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Here is my code:

```vb
Dim sError As String
Dim pSymbolSelector As ISymbolSelector
Dim pMarker As ISimpleMarkerSymbol
Dim pColour As IColor
Dim pCol As System.Drawing.Color
Dim iColour As Integer
Dim sName As String = ""
Dim dSize As Double
Dim sStartEnd As String = comboStEnd.Text
Dim iStyle As Integer = -1
Dim pSymbol As ISymbol
Dim pMSym As IMarkerSymbol
Dim pStyleStorage As IStyleGalleryStorage
Dim pStyleGallery As IStyleGallery
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pEnumStyleGall As IEnumStyleGalleryItem
Dim pStyleItem As IStyleGalleryItem
Dim pMarkerSym As IMarkerSymbol
Dim pMSymClone As IClone
Dim pMarkerClone As IClone

Try
    sError = ""
    StatusLabel1.Text = ""

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sStartEnd) Then
        StatusLabel1.Text = "Please choose Start or End"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    pSymbolSelector = New SymbolSelector

    pMarker = New SimpleMarkerSymbol
    If Not pSymbolSelector.AddSymbol(pMarker) Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf pSymbolSelector.SelectSymbol(0) Then
        pSymbol = pSymbolSelector.GetSymbolAt(0)
        pMSym = TryCast(pSymbol, IMarkerSymbol)
        If pMSym Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        dSize = pMSym.Size
        pColour = pMSym.Color
        pCol = New System.Drawing.Color
        pCol = modMain.colourESRItoMS(pColour, sError)
        If sError.Length > 0 Then
            sError = "cmdChoose;" & vbCrLf & sError
            MsgBox(sError)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        iColour = pCol.ToArgb


        pMSymClone = CType(pMSym, IClone)

        ' Get the symbol style
        pMxDoc = m_pApp.Document
        pStyleGallery = pMxDoc.StyleGallery
        pStyleStorage = pStyleGallery
        pEnumStyleGall = pStyleGallery.Items("Marker Symbols", "ESRI.Style", "Default")
        pEnumStyleGall.Reset()
        pStyleItem = pEnumStyleGall.Next
        While pStyleItem IsNot Nothing
            pMarkerSym = pStyleItem.Item
            pMarkerSym.Size = dSize
            pMarkerSym.Color = pColour
            pMarkerClone = CType(pMarkerSym, IClone)
            If pMSymClone.IsEqual(pMarkerClone) Then ' True if pMSym has not been modifed for size or colour
                sName = pStyleItem.Name
                iStyle = pStyleItem.ID
                Exit While
            End If
            pStyleItem = pEnumStyleGall.Next
        End While

    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    sError = "ERROR: cmdChoose; Line: " & Erl() & vbCrLf & ex.ToString
    MsgBox(sError)
End Try
```

Comment: You need to look at the other interfaces like ICharacterMarkerSymbol http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ICharacterMarkerSymbol_Interface/001w00000097000000/, see which interface the MarkerSymbol implements, cast it to that and then get the specific properties. It would also be a good idea to edit your question and add ArcObjects tag to help draw the right kind of attention to this question.

Comment: As I recall, the symbol selector dialog always returns an `IMultiLayerMarkerSymbol` - even when you choose what appears to be a simplemarker symbol.  In that case it would just contain one layer.